# CCID slot status byte

Tags: javascript, usb, smartcard-reader, pcsc

Reading the CCID specifications, I was wondering what is the intrinsic structure of the **Slot Status** (`bStatus` byte), set in the header of a response (*inbound bulk transfer*) message.

Only the first two and last two bits are used for `bmIccStatus` and `bmCommandStatus`, but I'm not sure how.

Given the (JavaScript) binary notation `0bxx0000yy`, is it true that `bmCommandStatus` is represented by `xx`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the (JavaScript) binary notation `0bxx0000yy`:

- `xx` .. bmCommandStatus (mask `0xC0`)
- `yy` .. bmICCStatus (mask `0x03`)

Reference [here](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/SmartCardServices/SmartCardServices-31/src/CCIDDriver/common/CCID.h) (I *did* check the CCID Rev 1.1, but was *unable* to find the bit order here -- i.e. MSB first or LSB first).

You might find using [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) extremely useful as it supports [USB sniffing](https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/USB) with [CCID support](https://vmlemon.wordpress.com/2012/03/04/new-wireshark-usb-ccid-dissector-functionality/).